# How to get the value of a dictionary of int only?

Tags: c#

Here's the idea: I get (in AJAX) a type of boat, which is an `int`. I want to make a "nice" way of getting the actual length of the boat.

In Python I'd do:

```
boat_lengths = {1:5, 2:4, 3:3, 4:3, 5:2}
return boat_lengths[t] if t in boat_lengths else -1
```

But I came up with this in C# and I guess there's a much better way of doing this:

```
// t is a string 
List<int> boatIndexes = new List<int> {
    1, // 'carrier'
    2, // 'battleship'
    3, // 'cruiser'
    4, // 'submarine'
    5 // 'destroyer'
};
int[] boatLengths = {
    5, // 'carrier'
    4, // 'battleship'
    3, // 'cruiser'
    3, // 'submarine'
    2  // 'destroyer'
};
int boatIdx = boatIndexes.IndexOf(t.ToInt32());
return boatLengths[boatIdx];
```

Comment: but `boatIndexes.IndexOf(t.ToInt32());` won't compile. please elaborate.

Comment: Why do you need anything but the second array?  What's the point of the first array when it simply provides a list of sequential `int` values?  The indexes of the elements in the second array is already a list of sequential `int` values so what's the use of the other array?  All you need to do is subtract 1 from the boat number and use that as an index into the second array.

Comment: If the indices can be any int value, you might need a `Dictionary<int, int>` - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Aominè Unless my eyes have a problem, my Unity program compiles & runs (t is a string, as I said at the very beginning in my code).

Comment: @OlivierPons it makes sense now. I didn't know you were using Unity.

Comment: Then I should apologize if my code will run only on Unity, not on other environments (which I didn't know, I'm very new to C#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` generic collection and use `TryGetValue` method. Then you will not need to use parsing method.

Example:

```
var boatLengths = new Dictionary<string, int> {
    {"1", 5},
    {"2", 4},
    {"3", 3},
    {"4", 3},
    {"5", 2}
};
int len;
return boatLengths.TryGetValue(t, out len) ? len : -1;
```

Comment: Rider suggests to remove the `()` of the initializer because it's redundant.